# SATA HDD compatibility

Tags: sata

I have a Fujitsu Siemens V5505 notebook, and it has a SATA I hard disk. Can I upgrade the disk to a SATA III unit?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a SATA 3 hard disk in it. It will run at SATA 1 speeds.